# How can I make menu with icons?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this UI

[image]

This is what I come up with.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row mp-header">

        <span class="mp-key"><span class="sprite circle-o"></span> No Assignment </span>
        <span class="mp-key"><span class="sprite db-circle-o"></span> Assignments in Progress </span>
        <span class="mp-key"><span class="sprite check-o"></span> Assignmments Completed </span>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mp-key{ display:flex; }
```

My result :

[image]

Here is my live result : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/x6pj4Lym/)

Can someone give me a little push here ?

Comment: try this `<span class="sprite circle-o"></span> <span>No Assignment</span>`, there is an extra `<span>` added.

Comment: Please can you provide full code that will enable us to reproduce the result you are getting?

Comment: Try using a pseudo selector.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: @HiddenHobbes : I update my post with a link to my Fiddle.

Comment: Who ever down voted may care to explain why?

Comment: They would have downvoted because there wasn't enough code to reproduce the error. With the fiddle you've provided this shouldn't be a problem anymore. Just for the record, I didn't downvote you because by my reckoning you put effort into your question, it was merely missing a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Thanks for your advice/explaination. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the `display: flex;` to the parent element of flex-items. To ge the desired result, you will need to alter your html (to keep it easy).

Here is one possible way:

```css
.flex-row {
    display:flex;
}
.flex-row > .mp-key {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row mp-header">
     <h2 class="mp-h2"> Monitor Progress: <span class="mp-h4">Sample Report</span></h2>
    <div class="flex-row"> 
        <span class="mp-key">
            <span class="sprite circle-o"></span> No Assignment
        </span>
        <span class="mp-key">
            <span class="sprite db-circle-o"></span> Assignments in Progress
        </span> 
        <span class="mp-key">
            <span class="sprite check-o"></span> Assignmments Completed
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

To complete your task, you can just put the sprites on the prepared `<span>` elements, and don't forget to use a `padding-left` of the width of the sprites so the alignment stays correct.

**Update**
Here is your updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6pj4Lym/2/

**relevant changes in the CSS of the jsFiddle:**

Changed all sprite margins to:

```
.sprite
{
    margin: 0 9px 0 0;
}
```

---

**Update 2:**

If you want the elements to get closer together you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/s524kory/

```
.flex-row {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flex-row > .mp-key {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Left aligned version: http://jsfiddle.net/s524kory/1/

Comment: Who ever down voted may care to explain why? (did anyone ever answered such a request?) ...

Comment: I agree. People always do that. I feel is very disrespectful.

Comment: No problem, the OP has included an image showing what the final output should be. The issue in particular is with the position of the icons, your answer does not address this. Now that @rangerover.js has provided the full code you should have everything you need replicate the image.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes thank you for your feedback. To the time the question was placed, there was no source of the images available. Also OP state "i need a push" and i saw that his problem related to the usage of flebox. Also I've allready updated the question with a jsFiddle link of the new material.

Comment: @NicoO : I like your answer. Can you make them closer to each other please just like the UI I posted? They're a bit far apart from each other right now. I will make sure to accept this answer. Update your fiddle link if you can.

Comment: @rangerover.js please see Update 2.

Comment: I saw the update 2. Thank you so much. Can you briefly explain `flex: 0 0 auto;` ? Also, why they're not align left, line up with my header ?

Comment: Here is the left-aligned solution: http://jsfiddle.net/s524kory/1/ [`flex: 0 0 auto;` is a shorthand property for: `flex-grow: 0 flex-shrink: 0 flex-basis: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex/)